# Enable all controls in 'Details' section of a MS Access 2010 Form using macro builder

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using MS Access 2010 Macro Builder, how could I enable all controls in 'Details' section of a Form?

I tried to create a public function:

```
Public Function EnableFrmControls()
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Detail.Controls
    If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox)
        ctrl.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Then to run this external function from a macro using:

RunCode Function Name: EnableFrmControls()

But didn't work due to compiler error in "For Each ctrl In Detail.Controls" line.

I expected the function would be called from an external function, but this didn't work for me! 
I get Run-time error '424':
Object required when I debug, I get a compiler error in "For Each ctrl In Detail.Controls" line.

Answer (score 1):

You missed form and section targeting:

```vb
Public Function EnableFrmControls(nameForm as string)
    Dim frmForm as Form
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Set frmForm = Forms(nameForm)

    For Each ctrl In frmForm.Section(acDetail).Controls
        If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox)
            ctrl.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next

    Set frmForm = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It seems to be perfect although I didn't try yet; moreover, is there any way to do the same procedure directly on the macro builder rather than calling the procedure from a module please?